# Sharing Playwright Tests Between Describes in Electron/Angular App

Tags: electron, playwright

I'm using Playwright to test an Electron/Angular application, which comes with some limitations. I have a few tests that are identical between different describe blocks. However, when I attempt to share these tests using a function and pass the mainWindow context, the mainWindow becomes undefined.

Here's my code structure:

```js
test.describe('My Page test', async () => {
    let electronApp: ElectronApplication;
    let context: BrowserContext;
    let mainWindow: Page;

    test.beforeAll(async () => {
      electronApp = await launchAppE2eUtils();
      context = electronApp.context();
      mainWindow = await launchApp(electronApp);
    });

    test.describe('Given a-b-c', async () => {
      let myObject;

      test.beforeAll(async () => {
        myObject = new MyObject(mainWindow);
      });

      // shared in all Givens
      test.describe('When the user clicks on the button', async () => {
        test('Then the user should see x', async () => {})
      })
    })
});
```

And here's the function I'm trying to use for sharing:

```js
function sharedTest(mainWindow) {
  test.describe('When the user clicks on the button', async () => {
   let myObject; 

    test.beforeAll(async () => {
      myObject = new MyObject(mainWindow); 
    });

    test('Then the user should see x', async () => {

      myobject.click()
    })
  })
}
```

How can I fix this issue and properly share the test.describe block while maintaining access to the mainWindow context within the shared function?